# Specify default join condition with sqlalchemy

Tags: python, join, sqlalchemy

I have two models:

```
class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I would like to specify default behaviour on `join`:

```
for row in session.query(Parent).join(Child):
   ...
```

Of course it produces the error `sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Don't know how to join to <Mapper at 0x7f812c10db50; Child>.` I am searching for a way to tell somewhere what should be done on join, so I don't need to write `session.query(Parent).join(Child, Parent.id == Child.parent_id)`.

There is one extra problem - **foreign key constraint is not an option in my case**

Full snippet:

```
from sqlalchemy import Column, Integer
from sqlalchemy.engine import create_engine

from sqlalchemy.orm import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm.session import sessionmaker

url = "postgresql://postgres:pass@127.0.0.1:5432"
engine = create_engine(url, echo=True)
Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()


class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = "child"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer)


class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)


Base.metadata.drop_all(engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(engine)

with Session() as s:
    for _ in s.query(Parent).join(Child):
        ...
```